# Making rMaps Leaflet Maps Full-screen

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, rcharts

I'm having some difficulty getting `rMaps` `leaflet` to be full-screen in `R`-`shiny`. Can anyone point me the right way on this?

ui.R:

```
library(shiny);library(rCharts)
shinyUI(navbarPage("rMaps Leaflet Sizing",
  tabPanel("Map",
#  tags$style('.leaflet {height: 100%; width: 100%}'), --no change 
    mapOutput('mapPlotJSON')
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny);library(rCharts);library(rMaps)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$mapPlotJSON <- renderMap({
    map1 = Leaflet$new()
    map1$setView(c(45.5236, -122.675), 13)
    map1$tileLayer(provider ='Stamen.Terrain')
#   map1$set(width = "100%", height = "100%") --doesn't show map
    map1
  })
})
```

Comment: You are putting the map inside a `navBarPage` that sizes the container inside. You can choose a large width and height `map1$set(width = 1600, height = 800)` as currently percent sizes are not supported. But note that `navBarPage` will still add padding that might offset the map. You will need more CSS to take care of that.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, Does anyone happen to know if there's a way to pass the user's screen resolution through `shiny`? That combined with this would be an answer but I may set that up as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I would suggest using the tips in the following page
http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/make-your-leafletjs-map-full-screen.html

e.g., in your .css file add:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.leaflet {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `map1$fullScreen(TRUE)`

See example in https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/290#issue-21794686

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Does that work for you? I'm still getting 800x400. 

Also, while it's not showing up, I want to recall `fullScreen` being a method that adds a button that enables full-screen viewing. 

To be more clear, I'm looking for it to automatically fill the page with the Navbar still showing. 

FYI, I have these loaded: rMaps_0.1.1 rCharts_0.4.2 shiny_0.10.1.

Comment: hi there, i have the same issue...any one knows a solution?